# log on to a webpage using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, authentication

I am totally new to this.

I was following examples I could find here and wrote the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

thisDirectory = 'my directory'

waitTime = 20

URL_entry = "https://www.capitaliq.com"
username = "my username"
password = "my password"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=thisDirectory + 
'\\chromedriver.exe')  
browser.get(URL_entry)

userNameBox = WebDriverWait(browser, waitTime).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="txtUsername"]'))
)
userNameBox.send_keys(username)

passwordBox = WebDriverWait(browser, waitTime).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="txtPwd"]'))
)
passwordBox.send_keys(password)
loginButton = WebDriverWait(browser, waitTime).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="butSignin"]'))
)
loginButton.click()
time.sleep(waitTime)
```

I also tried a few other slightly different methods but always getting the error message: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
TimeoutException: Message:

This is my first time posting here, sorry if I did anything inappropriate. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use wrong locators: there are no elements with `id` attributes `"txtUsername"`, `"txtPwd"`, `"butSignin"` on https://www.capitaliq.com login page...

Try below lines instead:

```
userNameBox = WebDriverWait(browser, waitTime).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'username'))
)

userNameBox.send_keys(username)

passwordBox = WebDriverWait(browser, waitTime).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'password'))
) 

passwordBox.send_keys(password)

loginButton = WebDriverWait(browser, waitTime).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'myLoginButton'))
)

loginButton.click()
```

Note that locators for elements in authorization form are not the same for all web-sites. To get exact locators you can do

right-click on element in browser -> select "Inspect element" -> check source code of target element... There you can find unique `id`/`name` values or other attributes that you can use [to locate element](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: A further question (please let me know if I should start a new post), if I want to **click on an image** on the same webpage "https://www.capitaliq.com", let's say the top left corner "S&P Global", what should I do? I tried finding the element by the src by it did not work. Thanks so much.

Comment: I tried 'browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[img/@src="my src"]').click()' but it did not work

Comment: It should be `//a[img[@src="/images/spgmi_logo.png"]]`